# porting jquery to java

Tags: java, jquery, porting

i have a jquery cod with me and i want to port it to java. Is there any options available to do this task quickly since i am not familiar with java

Here is my code

```
ASDR.PostStore = function(ec, options) {
        this.ec = ec;
        this.target = options && options.target;
        var self = this;

        var _send = function(url, transaction, pre, post) {
            $(transaction).trigger(pre);
            $(self).trigger(pre, transaction);
            $(self).trigger('sending', transaction);
            $.ajax({
                type    : "POST",
                url     : url,
                data    : transaction.toString(),
                dataType: "json",
                success : function(data) {
                    ec.expand(data, true);//Always updateOnIntern
                    $(self).trigger('sent', data);
                    $(self).trigger(post, data);
                    $(transaction).trigger(post, data);
                },
                error : function(data){
                    console.log("Logging error", data);
                }
            });
        };

        this.get = function(transaction) {
            var url = (this.target + "get");
            _send(url, transaction, 'getting', 'gotten');
        }

        this.persist = function(transaction) {
            var url = (this.target + "persist");
            _send(url, transaction, 'persisting', 'persisted');
        }

        /**
         * Always asynchronous.
         */
        this.is_async = function(){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Renjith Raj

Comment: are you sure you mean java and not javascript? What's your intent here? Your question doesn't really make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is `Javascript`, which is usually executed on the **client** side. Java is a program language which is executed on the **server** side. You cannot directly convert jQuery to Java.

You can however use a library such as [GWT](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/webtoolkit/) which translates Java to Javascript. There is also the possibility to statically render content server side. If you search for **JSP/JSTL** you'll find many resources.